# Haskell FFI - return updated structure

Tags: haskell, c2hs, haskell-ffi

I have the following `C` function that I want to call from `Haskell`:

```
void read_params_for (property_list_t *props);
```

The function is supposed to receive some `property_list_t` and populate some values within it, so the caller then has an updated structure.

I have all the necessary wrappers for `property_list_t` (like `Storable`, etc.), but I can't figure out how to wrap this function into something like

```
readParamsFor :: ForeignPtr PropertyListT -> IO (ForeignPtr PropertyListT)
```

I tried using `C2HS`, and I also tried writing FFI bindings manually like:

```
foreign import ccall "read_params_for"
    readParamsFor' :: Ptr PropertyListT -> IO ()

readParamsFor :: ForeignPtr PropertyListT -> IO (ForeignPtr PropertyListT)
readParamsFor ps = do
    withForeignPtr ps $ \ps' -> do
        res <- readParamsFor' ps'
        pl <- newForeignPtr propertyListDestroy ps'
        return pl
```

But in both cases, I get back my original "underpopulated" list.

How do I get an updated structure back to Haskell?

Comment: Well, `Foreign.Storable.poke`?

Comment: Why do you return another pointer? `ForeignPtr PropertyListT -> IO (ForeignPtr PropertyListT)` reads like `property_list_t *read_params_for(property_list_t *props)`. Since the latter returns `void`, I'd use `ForeignPtr PropertyListT -> IO ()` instead. You  shouldn't need `newForeignPtr` for this.

Comment: Your function can be written simply `readParamsFor p = withForeignPtr p readParamsFor' >> return p`; if this doesn't work, there is a problem with your implementation somewhere else (and since there is no verifiable example given, it's impossible to determine where that is). This is no different from returning the pointer given as input in the C function itself.

Comment: @user2407038 That's where I started from, but it didn't work and I assumed that it wasn't right. Looks like I have to check the actual C implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that there was a bug in a C library that I wanted to use and that indeed, a simple `withForeignPtr` is sufficient if the bug is not there.